# ACF unable to use user field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am totally new to wordpress and acf and I'm trying to use a user field in a post to show the author of the post. I tried to programatically add the post author id as a meta attribute in the wp_postmeta table like this:

```
update_field('video_author', get_current_user_id(), $post_id);
```

The post author, however, is not shown:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Also when I click the user field no users are listed. I presume acf looks for users in either "wp_users" or "users" table, both of which contain records. However, this is shown:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us all of the relevant information we need to be able to help. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  We don't know how your site is set up or what your ACF fields looks like, so please edit your to include all of the details that are needed to work out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect element your field , you will find key like `field_59c383916102a`

```
update_field( 'field_59c383916102a', get_current_user_id(), $post_id ); 
//Replace field_59c383916102a with your key value
```

Comment: I get the same result. This was inserted in wp_postmeta: https://imgur.com/a/dHKx9E6

Comment: Try this both :

`update_field( 'video_author', get_current_user_id(), $post_id );
update_field( '_video_author', get_current_user_id(), $post_id );`

Comment: Didn't work, this is the result in db: https://imgur.com/a/W0GfqtG

Comment: Try This :

update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_author', get_current_user_id() );
update_post_meta( $post_id , '_video_author', 'field_59c383916102a' ); //Replace field_59c383916102a with your key value

Comment: DB has the same content. Btw this is part of a field group if that changes anything.

Comment: *Btw this is part of a field group if that changes anything* - yes it does. You need to give us all of the relevant information in your question so we can help! Please edit your question to include enough information about the problem so that we can understand what might be happening and be able to help.